# Text to Speech - Google Maps and markers in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maps

I was trying to create Android app with Google Maps in it and some markers.
The thing is that I would like to have the functionality to read the text from these markers.
So I've added the first marker:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(52.4774762, 13.4245084))
            .title("Sahara Imbiss")
            .snippet("Very nice food here")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
```

so I would like to have a text from the snippet read out loud.

I found some templates with text to speech, e.g.

```
t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                t1.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            }
        }
    });
```

in onCreate and then the reading part:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            t1.speak("welcome to my app", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }, 100);
```

but I am not sure how to use it to read my snippet text.
I would like to add more markers and after e.g. clicking on them (is it a good idea) to have the text read from it.

Do you know how can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo implementation to achieve this.

```
package demo.maps.texttospeech;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    int ttsLang = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

                    if (ttsLang == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || ttsLang == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "The Language is not supported!");
                    } else {
                        Log.i("TTS", "Language Supported.");
                    }
                    Log.i("TTS", "Initialization success.");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TTS Initialization failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney")).setSnippet("Very nice food here");
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                String data = marker.getTitle() + " " + marker.getSnippet();
                Log.i("TTS", "button clicked: " + data);
                int speechStatus = textToSpeech.speak(data, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                if (speechStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    Log.e("TTS", "Error in converting Text to Speech!");
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Important pieces are to add a setOnMarkerClickListener to get your marker click events, and then build the string that you set to the marker as title and or snippet.

And initialise the TextToSpeech object in the onCreate and eventually call `textToSpeech.speak(data, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);` after the string is built in the click listener of the marker.

Thumbs up if this works!

Cheers!